# Show counter permanently even if it is on click

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, counter

I have the following code:

```
<body>
    <div class="block">
<button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button" class="button">Click me!</button>
<div  onload="clickCounter()" id="result"></div>
<button id="reset" class="button">Reset</button>
 </div>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}


function reset_counter() {
    localStorage.clickcount= 0;
}

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset_counter);
</script> 
</body>
```

When i reload the page, the value disappears until i click once more on the click me button, and I want the value to remain on the screen all the time. Can anyone modify the code so that the click me button only adds to the value, and the value is always shown on the screen?

Comment: Do you mean you want it to say 'You have clicked the button 0 time' when you initially arrive or do you want it to remember the clicks you've already done. So if you click 5 times then refresh it will say 'You have clicked the button 5 times' and if you clicked it again it would say 'You have clicked the button 6 times' etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to the bottom of your script to initialize the result before any clicking happens:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + (localStorage.clickcount || 0) + " time(s).";
```

This makes it so your value will be there on refresh.

Your reset function is also missing a piece to update the result:

```
function reset_counter() {
    localStorage.clickcount = 0;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
}
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g334tgby/1).

Comment: thank you! I'm a beginner and i needed a bit of help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

add onload to body

```
<body onload="showCounter();">
```

and add this function:

```
function showCounter(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;
}
```

it's works here 
https://jsfiddle.net/7qoqd7k9/